# Exception in using appclient jar in EJB 3 :javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException:

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I am trying to learn ejb 3 and facing an issue in the below mentioned scenario which I am not able to figure out.

1. I am having one Entity (Book) to store book related data.
2. I have created Stateless Bean and Remote interfaces and deployed the jar in glassfish 4.
3. The basic application connects to a main method where I need to get the details of the book using appclient. Here I am getting an error "javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException:"

Please look into the below snippets for more details.

Book.java:

```
package bookstore.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "findAllBooks", query = "select b from Book b")
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String title;
private Float price;
@Column(length = 2000)
private String description;
private String isbn;
private Integer nbOfPage;
private Boolean illustrations;
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "tag")
@Column(name = "Value")
private List<String> tags;

public List<String> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Float price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

public Integer getNbOfPage() {
    return nbOfPage;
}

public void setNbOfPage(Integer nbOfPage) {
    this.nbOfPage = nbOfPage;
}

public Boolean getIllustrations() {
    return illustrations;
}

public void setIllustrations(Boolean illustrations) {
    this.illustrations = illustrations;
}
}
```

BookEJBRemote.java:

```
package bookstore.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

import bookstore.model.Book;

@Remote
public interface BookEJBRemote {

    public List<Book> findBooks();

    public Book findBookById(long id);

    public Book createBook(Book book);

    public Book deleteBook(Book book);

    public Book updateBook(Book book);

}
```

BookEJB.java:
    package bookstore.controller;

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import bookstore.model.Book;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class BookEJB implements BookEJBRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "bookstore_persistence")
    private EntityManager em;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see bookstore.controller.BookEJBRemote#findBooks()
     */
    public List<Book> findBooks() {
        TypedQuery<Book> query = em
                .createNamedQuery("findAllBooks", Book.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see bookstore.controller.BookEJBRemote#findBookById(long)
     */
    public Book findBookById(long id) {
        return em.find(Book.class, id);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see bookstore.controller.BookEJBRemote#createBook(bookstore.model.Book)
     */
    public Book createBook(Book book) {
        em.persist(book);
        return book;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see bookstore.controller.BookEJBRemote#deleteBook(bookstore.model.Book)
     */
    public Book deleteBook(Book book) {
        em.remove(book);
        return book;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see bookstore.controller.BookEJBRemote#updateBook(bookstore.model.Book)
     */
    public Book updateBook(Book book) {

        return em.merge(book);
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="bookstore_persistence"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/mysqlPool</jta-data-source>
        <class>bookstore.model.Book</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging-level" value="INFO" />
            <!--  property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test_user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" /-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.sambaran</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sample-bookstore</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId> <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId> 
            <scope>runtime</scope> <version>2.6.0</version> </dependency> <dependency> 
            <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> <version>5.1.35</version> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>bookstore.client.BookStoreMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Main class BookstoreMain.java

```
package bookstore.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ejb.EJB;

import bookstore.controller.BookEJBRemote;
import bookstore.model.Book;


public class BookStoreMain {
    @EJB
    private static BookEJBRemote bookEJB;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Book book = new Book();
        book.setTitle("Head First Servlets and JSP");
        book.setDescription("A brain friendly guide.");
        book.setIllustrations(true);
        book.setIsbn("1-3244-3237676");
        book.setPrice(new Float(400.00));
        book.setNbOfPage(865);
        ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
        tags.add("java");
        tags.add("J2SE");
        book.setTags(tags);
        bookEJB.createBook(book);
        book.setTitle("Hear First SQL");
        bookEJB.updateBook(book);
        //bookEJB
    }

}
```

Deployment of ejb was successful using asadmin command. Please check the details below.

```
sambaran@sambaran-home:~/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin$ ./asadmin list-applications --type ejb
bookstore-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT  <ejb>


Command list-applications executed successfully.
```

When I try to use appclient to install the client it is having the mentioned error. PFB details.

```
sambaran@sambaran-home:~/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin$ ./appclient -client  /home/sambaran/workspace/bookstore/target/bookstore-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446343 No; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: FINE: 00810007: Underflow in BufferManagerReadStream after last fragment in message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.endOfStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerReadStream.underflow(BufferManagerReadStream.java:122)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_1.grow(CDRInputStream_1_1.java:111)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_2.alignAndCheck(CDRInputStream_1_2.java:126)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_long(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:433)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readValueTag(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1672)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:918)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:450)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:171)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
    at bookstore.controller._BookEJBRemote_Wrapper.createBook(bookstore/controller/_BookEJBRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at bookstore.client.BookStoreMain.main(BookStoreMain.java:28)
Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446343 No; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: FINE: 00810007: Underflow in BufferManagerReadStream after last fragment in message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.endOfStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerReadStream.underflow(BufferManagerReadStream.java:122)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_1.grow(CDRInputStream_1_1.java:111)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_2.alignAndCheck(CDRInputStream_1_2.java:126)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_long(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:433)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readValueTag(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1672)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:918)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:450)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:171)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:266)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at bookstore.controller.__BookEJBRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.createBook(bookstore/controller/__BookEJBRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: FINE: 00810007: Underflow in BufferManagerReadStream after last fragment in message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.endOfStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerReadStream.underflow(BufferManagerReadStream.java:122)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_1.grow(CDRInputStream_1_1.java:111)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_2.alignAndCheck(CDRInputStream_1_2.java:126)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_long(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:433)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readValueTag(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1672)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:918)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:450)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:171)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.getSystemException(MessageBase.java:813)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.ReplyMessage_1_2.getSystemException(ReplyMessage_1_2.java:131)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.getSystemExceptionReply(MessageMediatorImpl.java:594)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.processResponse(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:518)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:392)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.invoke(ClientDelegateImpl.java:258)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:198)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your entity class is not serialize, implement `Serializable` interface in your `Book` class

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "findAllBooks", query = "select b from Book b")
public class Book implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

...

}
```

hope it will help.