# GlassFish/Java can't return Integer

Tags: java, glassfish

I am new to GlassFish and now started by creating a simple Server - Client Communication. I got it to work but for some reason i get a Exeption by returning Integers. Strings work just fine.

RemoteInterface:

```
@Remote
public interface MySessionRemote {

    void setResult(String value);
    int getResult();

}
```

EJBModule:

```
@Singleton(mappedName="ejb/SessionBean")
public class SessionBean implements MySessionRemote, Serializable  {

    private String value = "Test";

    @Override
    public void setResult(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int getResult () {
        return this.value.length();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class Main {

    @EJB(mappedName="ejb/SessionBean")
    private static MySessionRemote mySession;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mySession.setResult("Hallo");
        int result = mySession.getResult();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Exceptions:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:446)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.main(AppClientFacade.java:166)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446343 No; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: FEIN: 00810007: Underflow in BufferManagerReadStream after last fragment in message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.endOfStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerReadStream.underflow(BufferManagerReadStream.java:122)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_1.grow(CDRInputStream_1_1.java:111)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_2.alignAndCheck(CDRInputStream_1_2.java:126)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_long(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:433)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readStringOrIndirection(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:470)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_codebase_URL(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1808)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:940)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:450)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:171)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html - Beans' properties are supposed to have one single Type. So `setXXX(String value)` => **`String`** `getXXX()`

Comment: But you could define another (read-only) property that returns that int. For example name it "getResultLength".

Comment: If i got this right, if my result variable is a integer and the parameter of the set function also is a integer, it should work, but it doesn't but indeed i get a different error

Comment: I just pasted the whole stacktrace for the only Integer option

Comment: I just googled that error "javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446343" and found some referecnes on stackoverflow. Maybe use the search and find something helpful. Top hits were http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751951/using-an-ejb-3-1-bean-through-a-remote-java-stand-alone-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794869/exception-in-using-appclient-jar-in-ejb-3-javax-ejb-ejbexception-java-rmi-mars

Comment: I have seen both of them before, they both use own classes to return i know that they have to be serializable but i am using an Integer, so that should work anyway, shouldn't it?

Comment: I just changed some code to gain more information, the error is only thrown then i pass a integer as a parameter, returning integers work fine, i thought both make problems.

Comment: I got it to work now. I had to stop the glassfish server clean and build every single project again and then deploy them again. But i am still asking myself if there is a more comfortable way to deploy the project correctly that it works instantly.

Comment: Are you working on Windows? There were a few problems with undeployment in GlassFish that we've fixed in Payara Server that meant undeploying an application didn't always get rid of everything due to the way Windows uses file handles.